# GeoNetwork (Map mode) : Load a PostGIS table directly?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geonetwork

With GeoNetwork, within the map mode, is it possible to load a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table directly?

For instance, using a TCP/IP protocol (or another way), or we are obliged to load GIS data via a web service (WMS/WFS OGC service) or KML file.

[image: GeoNetwork map add layer]

Comment: The services tab is only for services using defined protocols.

Answer (score 2):

No. GeoNetwork doesn't support to load geographic data directly from Postgis (at least in current 3.12 or 4.2 versions).
You need a third party software component, like Geoserver or Mapserver, for rendering the Postgis table using WMS/WMTS protocols if you want to show that data in GeoNetwork.